# IDE для iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++

Собственно купил iPhone, хочу его убить (программно). Подскажите, где взять среду разработки для компиляции ipa приложений? (Я слышал там какая-то Aero... что-то там вышла). Очень заинтересовало :) Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: c++ здесь явно лишний...

Comment: Да-да... забыл упомянуть, что придётся ещё изучать Objective-C...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, в первую очередь, это, конечно же родная [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html). Остальные альтернативы почти наверняка окажутся неполноценными. Как минимум, вам наверняка понадобится компилятор, эмулятор и прочие сопутствующие инструменты, идущие с Xcode в комплекте.